# hyperplanes and hypersurfaces in affine spaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $\mathbb{A}^{n}$ be the $n$-dimensional affine space over a field $k$ and $H$ an arbitrary hypersurface of $\mathbb{A}^{n}$.

> **Q.** Does there exist a hyperplane $P$ such that $P \cap H =\emptyset$?

Comment: For instance, take as $H$ the union of two non-parallel hyperplanes. Then no hyperplane can be disjoint from $H$.

Comment: @DonuArapura.  Just to clarify: you are saying that for every $n\geq 2$, there exists $H$ a hypersurface such that for every $P$, the intersection is nonempty (i.e., answering the question for "arbitrary" hypersurfaces).  Of course for some special $H$, there can exist $P$ with empty intersection, i.e., if $H$ is the zero scheme of $1+x_nf(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ and $P$ is the zero scheme of $x_n$.

Comment: Yes, I deleted my comment. Somehow I was thinking projectively...

Comment: @DonuArapura.  I believe that your comment was completely correct as an answer to the question asked (with the word "arbitrary" emphasized).

Comment: I think my example shows that the answer is negative, or am I missing something trivial?

Comment: Francesco and Jason, yes it  does fail for *arbitrary* $H$, but  its not completely clear to me what the OP wants.

Comment: Probably you meant 
 Converse theorem for separation theorem see this :https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperplane_separation_theorem

Comment: @zeraouliarafik: how is this related to the OP's question?

Comment: What about a hyperboloid, $x^2 + y^2 - z^2 = 1$?

Comment: Any general hypersurface (of degree at least 2) has no non-trivial units and then no hyperplane can be disjoint from it.

Answer (score 4):

Let me expand my comment into a (negative) answer, so the question will not appear unanswered anymore.

Let us take as $H$ the union of two non-parallel hyperplanes of $\mathbb{A}^n$. Then, clearly, there exists no hyperplane $P$ disjoint from $H$.

In fact, as remarked by Mohan, a general affine hypersurface of $\mathbb{A}^n$ of degree at least $2$ intersects every hyperplane.